# UIProgressView progress value rounds

Tags: ios, objective-c

A have an issue with UIProgressView value. I'm trying to embed ProgressView into Table View cell. 
This code works - ProgressView fills it's cell. But there's problem with filling ProgressView itself - it's value rounds to 0.5 (e.g. if value is 0.2 then progressView is not filled, if 0.8 - then it filled 100%, see the image bellow)
Can anyone help with making things right?

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
cell.attendanceProgress.transform = transform;
[cell.attendanceProgress setAlpha:0.5];
[cell setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
float progr = (float)attended / (float)classes.count;
if (classes.count == 0) { progr = 0; }
[cell.attendanceProgress setProgress:progr];
```

[image: displays in app]

Comment: what is attended?

Comment: i mean data type of attended?

Comment: @ajay_nasa integer

Comment: By the way, if delete first two lines (with transformation) everything works just fine (however it looks like a standard thin line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
cell.attendanceProgress.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,cell.attendanceProgress.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DScale(cell.attendanceProgress.layer.transform, 1.0f,cell.frame.size.height, 1.0f);
cell.attendanceProgress.layer.transform = transform;
```

Make sure set frame before transform.

Comment: let me know, is this you want? I will edit as required.

Comment: This helped! Thank you :)